# Open source Erp

Tags: open-source, erp

In 2017 what open source erp is recommended?

- Odoo most features are paid
- Ofbiz is completely open-source but it have not not very large community
- Opentaps is dead

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you're interested in something you didn't mention, and which is:

- **NOT** paid.
- **ALSO** completely open-source.
- **NOT** dead.

Have a look at [ERPAL for Service Providers](https://www.drupal.org/project/erpal), which is a "distribution" using [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/) (version 7). Some more details (from its project page):

> ERPAL is a centralized and web based business management distribution for software developers and service providers. It enables you to manage business processes with ONE smart toolbox that includes all the following features out of the box:
>
> - CRM (contact and activity management)
> - Project management (timetracking, payments, Agil and fixed price, expenses, Gantt charts, requirement management) with Freelancer support
> - Document management and document creation
> - Contract management with recurring invoices
> - Employee management (overtime, holidays, costs)
> - Invoice creation and PDF export
> - Calendars
> - ...and many other features
>
> ERPAL's goal is to have ONE TOOL to consolidate all the different business processes to reduce the time you spend with administration and project controlling. The ERPAL system enables you to manage all your everyday business tasks in one integrated smart solution.

Many more details about it can be found via the link above.